# I can't print the data from service to angular dart component

Tags: angular, dart, service

I am mocking up the data and in future this data will be called from an API. Following is the code I have done so far.

Dart model class:

```
class Main {
  final int id;
  String date;
  String orderID;
  String customer;
  String answeredBy;
  String requestType;

  Main(this.id, this.date, this.orderID, this.customer,
       this.answeredBy, this.requestType);

  @override
  String toString() =>
      '$id: $date: $orderID: $customer: $answeredBy: $requestType';
}
```

Dart service class:

```
@Injectable()
class MainService {
 Future<List<Main>> getAll() async => main_mock_data;
}
```

Mock up data:

```
import 'main.dart';

final main_mock_data = <Main>[
 Main(1, '12-1-2020', 'orderID', 'customer', 'answeredBy', 'requestType'),
];
```

app_component.dart

```
@Component(
    selector: 'app-main',
    styleUrls: ['main_component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'main_component.html',
    providers: [ClassProvider(MainService)])

class MainComponent implements OnInit {
     final MainService _mainService; // defining private property
    
     List<Main> data;
     Main selected;
    
     MainComponent(this._mainService);
    
     Future<void> _getTableData() async {
         data = await _mainService.getAll();
     }
    
     void ngOnInit() => _getTableData();
}
```

And finally html file:

```
  <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
    <td>{{item.Date}}</td>
    <td>{{item.OrderID}}</td>
    <td>{{item.Customer}}</td>
    <td>{{item.AnsweredBy}}</td>
    <td>{{item.RequestType}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular will trigger change detection when some events happen in the current window (click, timer, xhr call ...)

You can use a timer to 'emulate' and xhr call instead of directly returning you mocking data

```dart
Future<List<Main>> getAll() {
  return Future.delayed(
    Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    () => main_mock_data,
  );
}
```

Or you can manually trigger change detection.

```dart
final ChangeDetectorRef changeDetection;
MainComponent(this._mainService, this.changeDetection);

Future<void> _getTableData() async {
  data = await _mainService.getAll();
  changeDetection.markForCheck()
}
```